# Implementar un CountDown Timer en un servicio

Tags: android, servicio

Tengo un botón que al presionarse comienza una cuenta atrás, y deseo que esta cuenta se mantenga hasta que termine aun cuando la app se cierre o se cambie de `Activity`. Tengo entendido que una forma de hacerlo es usar un servicio en segundo plano, pero he leído pero no lo logro entender como implementarlo. Gracias !

Clase para el servicio

```
package com.example.ash.carritosbeta1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ServicioTimer extends Service {

    String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
    private static String TAG = "Servicio";
    public static final String PAQETE = "com.example.ash.carritosbeta1"; //ejemplo com.proyecto.MainActivity
    Intent bi = new Intent(PAQETE);

    CountDownTimer cdt = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Comienza el timer...");
        cdt = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String tiempo = ""+String.format(FORMAT,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

                //con esto se envia el tiempo
                bi.putExtra("Tiempo", tiempo);
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                //se envia el tiempo finalizado
                bi.putExtra("Fin", "Tiempo terminado!");
                sendBroadcast(bi);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelado");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Activity

```
public class tiempo_carro1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String TAG = "Servicio";
    TextView contador;
    Button inicar, pausar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiempo_carro1);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        contador=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrar);
        contador.setText("00:00:00");
        inicar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.iniciar);
        inicar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //inicia el servicio
                startService(new Intent(tiempo_carro1.this, ServicioTimer.class));

            }
        });
        pausar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Reinicar);
        pausar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


    }
    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //aqui obtienes los datos enviados por el servicio
            //obtienes el tiempo que lleva
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                if (intent.hasExtra("Tiempo")) {
                    String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Tiempo");
                    contador.setText(tiempo);
                } if (intent.hasExtra("Fin")) {
                    //se recibe que se ha finalizado el contador
                    String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Fin");
                    contador.setText(tiempo);
                    inicar.setEnabled(true);
                    //cierras el servicio ya que no es necesario mantenerlo, sera creado al pulsar el boton nuevamente
                    stopService(new Intent(tiempo_carro1.this, ServicioTimer.class));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(ServicioTimer.PAQETE));
        Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast registrado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast desligado");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(tiempo_carro1.this, ServicioTimer.class));
        Log.i(TAG, "Termina el servicioo");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paso a explicarte la manera en la que yo lo haría, el funcionamiento es el siguiente; Se crea un servicio como bien has indicado, el cual se hará cargo de ejecutar la cuenta atrás, éste sera ejecutado desde la actividad al presionar el botón. En la misma actividad, se crea una "escucha" usando un `BroadcastReceiver` el cual recibirá la información que del servicio tal como el tiempo transcurrido, o cuando finaliza. Si la actividad se cierra, se elimina la escucha de dicho broadcast, si es destruida, se termina el servicio; Estos últimos comportamientos puedes modificarlos según tu preferencia.
La implementación podría ser de la siguiente manera:

SERVICIO:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ServicioTimer extends Service {

String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
private static String TAG = "Servicio";
public static final String PAQETE = "nombre_de_tu_paquete.nombre_atividad"; //ejemplo com.proyecto.MainActivity
Intent bi = new Intent(PAQETE);

CountDownTimer cdt = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "Comienza el timer...");
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String tiempo = ""+String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

            //con esto se envia el tiempo
            bi.putExtra("Tiempo", tiempo);
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            //se envia el tiempo finalizado
            bi.putExtra("Fin", "Tiempo terminado!");
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cdt.cancel();
    Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelado");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

ACTIVITY:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String TAG = "Servicio";

TextView contador;
Button iniciar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contador = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador);
    iniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iniciar);
    iniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iniciar.setEnabled(false);
            //inicia el servicio
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicioTimer.class));
        }
    });
}

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //aqui obtienes los datos enviados por el servicio
        //obtienes el tiempo que lleva
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            if (intent.hasExtra("Tiempo")) {
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Tiempo");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
            } if (intent.hasExtra("Fin")) {
                //se recibe que se ha finalizado el contador
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Fin");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
                iniciar.setEnabled(true);
                //cierras el servicio ya que no es necesario mantenerlo, sera creado al pulsar el boton nuevamente
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicioTimer.class));
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(ServicioTimer.PAQETE));
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast registrado");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast desligado");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicioTimer.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Termina el servicio");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

MANIFEST:

```
<service android:name=".ServicioTimer"/>
```

Obviar algún pequeño detalle como que coloques tu `FORMAT` y lo ordenes a tu preferencia y necesidades, me he tomado la libertad de agregar pequeños comentarios en el código y Logs para que te ayuden a identificar las cosas, cualquier duda puedes dejar un comentario y la intentaré solventar lo antes posible.

EDITO:
Para complementar mi respuesta, agrego un [link al código en GitHub](https://github.com/kingcreek/Count-Down-Persistant-Android), esta solventado el tema de la persistencia si la aplicación es cerrada, y al re-abrirla continue la cuenta regresiva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta primero que nada, una duda en mi paquete del inicio de la clase es com.example.ash.carritosbeta1 se coloca completo tal cual ?

Comment: Si, realmente esa parte de código es un identificador para que tu activity reciba el broadcast únicamente de tu servicio, puedes colocar lo que indicas sin problema

Comment: entiendo, pero no mustra el contador, pero si cierro la activity dice servicio terminado por el log

Comment: El código que he puesto en mi respuesta lo he ejecutado antes y esta completamente funcional, revisa que no se te haya pasado nada por alto, si lo deseas edita tu pregunta agregando como tienes el código actual y poder ver donde esta el error

Comment: He editado la pregunta, gracias !

Comment: En tu código no se ve ningún problema y es completamente funcional; Agregaste en tu `AndroidManifest` el servicio ? `<service android:name=".ServicioTimer"/>`

Comment: Si lo he agregado, si no me muestra ningun error, no entiendo por que no muestra el contador en el textview

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64461/discussion-between-israel-and-ash).

Answer (score -1):

Si no les corre debe ser por la ruta que le pusieron al servicio en el manifes o puede ser uno de los posibles errores ya que a mi me paso, lo metí dentro de una carpeta donde manejo todas las clases por lo que no me lograba encontrar el servicio y aun así me corría la aplicación pero no me mostraba la cuenta regresiva